# How to evaluate bool statements

Tags: xcode, file, boolean

I have a piece of code which is said to return a bool value.  I am a new programmer, so could someone give me code that will determine if the file at the path exists?

```
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.txt"]; //returns a bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy the stringByAppendingPathComponent: method does not return (BOOL) it returns (NSString *).

You can tell by looking at its signature which is:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)str;
```

If it did return a bool (which it does not,)  all you would have to do is: `if (path) {//...}`

What you actually want to do to test if a file exists is:

```
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.txt"]; 
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) {
  //File Exists So Code Goes Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a variable contains a boolean value, you can just test it whith:

```
if(var) {
   // gets executed if var is true
}
```

Read about [conditional control structurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29).

But `stringByAppendingPathComponent` does not return a boolean value, [it returns a string](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString).